# need to store echo output into variable and followed by string comparison in .mk file

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

Working on some implementaion in .mk file.

My Requirement is to assign echo output (string) to variable(eg. temp).

followed by string comparison need to do.

My case is working in .mk file(for printing on console)

echo "$$($$(VEN)_NAME) $$($$(VEN)_VERSION)" >>>>>HELLOWORLD_x-y-z
TEMP_VAR="HELLOWORLD_x-y-z"
echo "**********$$**TEMP_VAR***" ---->giving ********HELLOWORLD_x-y-z*** on console.

but i tried below things to store into temp variable,its not at all working.

$$temp=`(echo "$$($$(VEN)_NAME) $$($$(VEN)_VERSION)")`\
temp=`(echo "$$($$(VEN)_NAME) $$($$(VEN)_VERSION)")`\
$$temp=`(echo "$$($$(VEN)_NAME) $$($$(VEN)_VERSION)");\
temp = $$($$(VEN)_NAME) $$($$(VEN)_VERSION)\

for string comparision.
have to do these two variable TEMP_VAR ,temp
i'm new to .mk file,kindly guide me to do this.

Thanks,
ngmns.

Comment: Please read the documentation for the [`shell` function](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Shell-Function).

Comment: Your question is a bit hard to understand, but I guess that you also need to understand when variable values are assigned/evaluated in make, see https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Flavors

Answer (score 0):

I believe you want to do the below; A sample/simple GNU make file where echo output is assigned to a variable. Please note above is for GNU Makefile

```
tmp=`echo hello`
all:
   echo $(tmp)
```

Putting your echo command between `` will assign it to the variable.

Comment: Thank you for your help.

temp="$$($$(VEN)_NAME) $$($$(VEN)_VERSION)";\
then
echo "$$$$temp";\ --> Got printed.
echo "Checking:$$(PKG_FILE)";\ --> Got printed.
Now i want to compare two strings using ifeq.
got error when i use .mk file.
>>>/bin/sh: -c: line 0: syntax error near unexpected token `"$temp",""pkg.tar.gz""'

in .mk file
**********
ifeq ("$$$$temp","$$(PKG_FILE)") --> Something doing wrong here. ?

Comment: Looks like a separate question; Additionally, your question is not well articulated. Please create a new well articulated question. Also if the answer to this thread is satisfactory please accept the answer.